# How to call function from other script in arduino

Tags: arduino

Hi i have my script which is running completely fine .But it is too long because of its menu part. i need to write the menu to separate script and call that separate script in to my main script so that my code looks good how i can do this . This is my main script menu part that i need to write it separate script and call it from main script how to include it and how to call this function.

```
  // ========================================== Start of MENU:
        if (menu1==1){
  if (myEnc.getCount()>oldenc+8){MODE=MODE+1; oldenc=myEnc.getCount();}
  if (myEnc.getCount()<oldenc-8){MODE=MODE-1; oldenc=myEnc.getCount();}
  if (MODE<1){MODE=4;}
  if (MODE>4){MODE=1;}
  lcd.setCursor(0,0); lcd.print(">");
 // Serial.print("MODE :"), Serial.println(MODE);
  lcd.setCursor(1,0);
  if (MODE==1){lcd.print(String("CMV-P "));}
  if (MODE==2){lcd.print(String("CMV-V "));}
  if (MODE==3){lcd.print(String("SIMVP"));}
  if (MODE==4){lcd.print(String("SIMVV"));}
  if (MODE==5){lcd.print(String("PS-CP "));}
 // Serial.print(" F:"), Serial.println(MODE);
  }    
  if (menu1!=1 ){lcd.setCursor(0,0);lcd.print(" ");}
  if (menu1==2){
    if (myEnc.getCount()>oldenc+8){BPM=BPM+1; oldenc=myEnc.getCount();}
    if (myEnc.getCount()<oldenc-8){BPM=BPM-1; oldenc=myEnc.getCount();}
    if (BPM<12){BPM=12;}
    if (BPM>30){BPM=30;}
    lcd.setCursor(6,0);lcd.print(">");
    lcd.setCursor(7,0);lcd.print(String("BPM:")+String(BPM));
    Serial.print(" G:"), Serial.println(BPM);
  }
 if (menu1!=2){lcd.setCursor(6,0);lcd.print(" ");}
 if (menu1==3){
    if (myEnc.getCount()>oldenc+8){IE=IE+0.1; oldenc=myEnc.getCount();}
    if (myEnc.getCount()<oldenc-8){IE=IE-0.1; oldenc=myEnc.getCount();}
    if (IE>4){IE=4;}
    if (IE<1){IE=1;}

    sprintf(buff, "%3.1f", IE);
    lcd.setCursor(13,0); lcd.print(">");
    lcd.setCursor(14,0);lcd.print(String("IE:")+buff);
    Serial.print(" H:"), Serial.println(IE);
  }
  if (menu1!=3 && menu1!=9){lcd.setCursor(13,0);lcd.print(" ");}
  if (menu1==4){
    if (myEnc.getCount()>oldenc+8){PRES=PRES+1; PSync=0; oldenc=myEnc.getCount();}
    if (myEnc.getCount()<oldenc-8){PRES=PRES-1; PSync=0; oldenc=myEnc.getCount();}
    if (PRES>50){PRES=50;}
    if (PRES<10){PRES=10;}
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);lcd.print(">");
    lcd.setCursor(1,1);lcd.print(String("Pr:")+String(PRES));
    Serial.print(" I:"), Serial.println(PRES);
    }
    if (menu1!=4 && menu1!=9){lcd.setCursor(0,1);lcd.print(" ");}
    if (menu1==5){
    if (myEnc.getCount()>oldenc+8){TV=TV+10; oldenc=myEnc.getCount();}
    if (myEnc.getCount()<oldenc-8){TV=TV-10; oldenc=myEnc.getCount();}
    if (TV<250){TV=250;}
    if (TV>700){TV=700;}
    lcd.setCursor(6,1); lcd.print(">");
    lcd.setCursor(7,1);lcd.print(String("TV:")+String(TV));
    Serial.print(" J:"), Serial.println(TV);
  }
  if (menu1!=5 && menu1!=9){lcd.setCursor(6,1);lcd.print(" ");}
  if (menu1==6){
    if (myEnc.getCount()>oldenc+8){FIOD=FIOD+5; oldenc=myEnc.getCount();}
    if (myEnc.getCount()<oldenc-8){FIOD=FIOD-5; oldenc=myEnc.getCount();}
    FIO=FIOD;
    if(FIOD<=20){FIOD=20; FIO=21;}
    if(FIOD>99){FIOD=99; FIO=99;}
    lcd.setCursor(13,1);lcd.print(">");
    lcd.setCursor(14,1);lcd.print(String("FIO:")+String(FIO));
    Serial.print(" K:"), Serial.println(FIO);
  }
  if (menu1!=6 && menu1!=9){lcd.setCursor(13,1); lcd.print(" "); }
     if (menu1==7){
      if (myEnc.getCount()>oldenc+8){PEEP=PEEP+1; oldenc=myEnc.getCount();}
      if (myEnc.getCount()<oldenc-8){PEEP=PEEP-1; oldenc=myEnc.getCount();}
      if(PEEP<2){PEEP=2;}
      if(PEEP>25){PEEP=25;}
      lcd.setCursor(0,2);lcd.print(">");
      sprintf(buff, "%02d", PEEP);
      lcd.setCursor(1,2);lcd.print(String("PEEP:")+buff);
      Serial.print(" L:"), Serial.println(PEEP);
  }
  if (menu1!=7 && menu1!=9){lcd.setCursor(0,2);lcd.print(" ");}

  if (menu1==8){
    if (myEnc.getCount()>oldenc+8){TRIGSEN=TRIGSEN+1; oldenc=myEnc.getCount();}
    if (myEnc.getCount()<oldenc-8){TRIGSEN=TRIGSEN-1; oldenc=myEnc.getCount();}
    if(TRIGSEN<2){TRIGSEN=2;}
    if(TRIGSEN>20){TRIGSEN=20;}
    lcd.setCursor(8,2); lcd.print(">");
    lcd.setCursor(9,2);lcd.print(String("TRG:")+String(TRIGSEN));
    Serial.print(" M:"), Serial.println(TRIGSEN);
    }
  if (menu1!=8 && menu1!=9){lcd.setCursor(8,2);lcd.print(" ");}
  //================ END OF MENU


      delay(10);
  //    Serial.print(" PRS:"), Serial.print(PrsMed.getMedian());
    } // End of main loop
```

Comment: This isn't a "script."  It's compiled to firmware.  There is a fundamental difference.

Answer (score -1):

Write script in separate file with .ino extension and add that file in same arduino project directory.

Comment: from that script i need to call one function only.